# Excel VBA .Filter on Access Recordset with single quotes in the filter string

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have records in a Microsoft Access table. I'm trying to filter them with Excel VBA.

I can query the table fine and create a recordset. In the table there's a field "Row_Label". I want to see if the recordset contains a value "Tim's Roofing" in that column. I know I need to escape it somehow but every method for doing that is failing.

This is the .Filter expression

```
dim str as string
str = "[Row_Label] = """ & "Tim's Roofing" & """"            
accessRSExistLabels.Filter = str
```

when I run this code, I get the error

> Run-time error '3001':
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
> in conflict with one another.

When I change the code to

```
str = "[Row_Label]='Test'"            
accessRSExistLabels.Filter = str
```

It works fine, so I (think) this is an escaping issue and I'm doing it wrong, but I can't get .Filter to work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `str = Replace(str, "'","''")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use my `CSql` function:

```vb
str = "[Row_Label] = " & CSql("Tim's Roofing")
' xstr -> [Row_Label] =  'Tim''s Roofing'
```

```vb
' Converts a value of any type to its string representation.
' The function can be concatenated into an SQL expression as is
' without any delimiters or leading/trailing white-space.
'
' Examples:
'   SQL = "Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]>" & CSql(12.5) & "And [DueDate]<" & CSql(Date) & ""
'   SQL -> Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]> 12.5 And [DueDate]< #2016/01/30 00:00:00#
'
'   SQL = "Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values (" & CSql(" ") & ")"
'   SQL -> Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values ( Null )
'
' Trims text variables for leading/trailing Space and secures single quotes.
' Replaces zero length strings with Null.
' Formats date/time variables as safe string expressions.
' Uses Str to format decimal values to string expressions.
' Returns Null for values that cannot be expressed with a string expression.
'
' 2021-06-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CSql( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As String

    Const TypeLongLong  As Long = 20
    Const SqlNull       As String = " Null"

    Dim Sql             As String

    #If Win64 Then
        ' VBA.VarType.vbLongLong exists.
    #Else
        Dim vbLongLong  As Integer
        vbLongLong = TypeLongLong
    #End If

    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty            '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull             '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger          '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong             '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle           '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble           '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency         '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate             '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString           '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''"), """", """""")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = " '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject           '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError            '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean          '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant          '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject       '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal          '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte             '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLongLong         '   20  LongLong integer (Relevant on 64-bit platforms only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType  '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray            ' 8192  Array.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else               '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select

    CSql = Sql & " "

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
str = "[Row_Label] = '" & "Tim''s Roofing" & "'"
```

Single `'` need to be doubled-up